# Mysql Query not returning my results when adding variables into the query

Tags: php, mysql

If I run this with the query

```
"SELECT * FROM users";
```

It returns my result. But as soon as I run this

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$login = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name= ".$username." AND password= ".$password."";
```

it doesn't.

If I run it in Mysql workbench without the variables it works. If I run echo the $_POST values they come through correctly.
I am stumped as to what I'm doing wrong PLEASE!! help me.
I also ran my code through https://phpcodechecker.com/ and it cant see any errors in my code.
This is the full function.

```
function login($username,$password){
global $db_conn;
$conn = new mysqli($db_conn['servername'], $db_conn['username'], $db_conn['password'], $db_conn['dbname']);
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$login = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name= ".$username." AND password= ".$password."";
    $login_result = $conn->query($login);

    if ($login_result->num_rows > 0) {

        $output = array();
        while($row = $login_result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $output[] = $row;
            echo "".$row['name']."-".$row['password']."<br>";
        }
        } else {
            echo "Invaild Login Details!"."<br>" ;
            $conn->close();
            return false;
        }
}
```

Every time it says  "Invalid Login Details!" But I know their is one result that gets returned.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Inserting variables into your SQL directly is a major source of SQL Injection Attacks. Use PDO for security.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php#114974

Comment: $login = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name= `'`".$username."`'` AND password= `'`".$password."`'`"; how about add a single quote for the variable

Comment: let me try now quickly :D will get back top you now.

Comment: What does echo $login; return? Does the pw contain sql specific chars?

Comment: be conscious that these sql queries are [good candidates to sql injection risk](http://bobby-tables.com/), you should use prepared statements

Comment: Why does that cause it not to echo?

Comment: It fixed my query. But why does that break it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the query like this

```
$login = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name= '$username' AND password= '$password'";
```

note: this method is prone to sql injection attacks. try prepared statements to avoid it

Answer (score 0):

try with `''(single quote)` for comparing `name and password`

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name= '".$username."' AND password= '".$password."'";
```

Comment: whats wrong with this query

Comment: there is nothing wrong with this query. may be he doesn't know how to write code with proper php syntax.

Answer (score -1):

```
$login = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '{$username}' AND password = 
'{$password}' ";
```

Comment: It would be useful to add a short explanation about what your code does.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply specify the variables no need to go for string append to construct query in php

Eg :

```
Query = "SELECT * FROM `users` where username = '$username' AND  password = '$password' " ;
```

Answer (score -1):

try following code

```
$login = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name= '".$username."' AND password= '".$password."'";
```